# how to put text between a specific width and length in canvas-constructor

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord.js

is there any way to put those `vvvv` inside the white box till the place where the black line is there
`like it starts from the end of the blue color and ends at that black line in the white color and the whole paragraph stays inside it`

[image]

Code

```js
const { Canvas } = require('canvas-constructor');
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const { get } = require('node-superfetch');
const db = require('quick.db');
const fsn = require('fs-nextra');
const { crFormat } = require('../../functions')

Canvas.registerFont(`${process.cwd()}/assets/font/NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf`, "NotoEmoji")
Canvas.registerFont(`${process.cwd()}/assets/font/Roboto-Regular.ttf`, "RobotoRegular")

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "profile2",
        aliases: ['prof'],
        category: 'economy',
        description: 'Shows User Profile',
        usage: '[mention | username | nickname | ID]',
        accessableby: "everyone"
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {

        let user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.user.username.toLowerCase() === args.join(' ').toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.guild.members.cache.find(r => r.displayName.toLowerCase() === args.join(' ').toLocaleLowerCase()) || message.member;
        if (user.user.bot) return message.channel.send(`**Bots Don't Have A Profile!**`);

        let works = await db.fetch(`works_${user.id}`)
        if (works === null) works = 0;

        let bg = await db.fetch(`bg_${user.id}`)
        if (bg === null) bg = 'https://images.wallpaperscraft.com/image/cat_profile_muzzle_eyes_113734_3840x2400.jpg'

        let money = await db.fetch(`money_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
        if (money === null) money = 0;

        let bank = await db.fetch(`bank_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
        if (bank === null) bank = 0;

        let level = await db.fetch(`level_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
        if (level === null) level = 0;

        let info = await db.fetch(`info_${user.id}`)
        if (info === null) info = 'No Info'

        let xp = await db.fetch(`messages_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
        if (xp == null) xp = 1

        let vip = await db.fetch(`bronze_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
        if (vip === null) vip = '0'
        if (vip === true) vip = '1'

        let shoes = await db.fetch(`nikes_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
        if (shoes === null) shoes = '0'

        let newcar = await db.fetch(`car_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
        if (newcar === null) newcar = '0'

        let newhouse = await db.fetch(`house_${message.guild.id}_${user.id}`)
        if (newhouse === null) newhouse = '0'

        let uLevel = level + 1;
        let nxtLvlXp = uLevel * 100;
        let difference = xp / nxtLvlXp * 297;
        let balance = money;
        let Info = info
        let background = bg;
        let work = works;

        try {
            async function createCanvas() {
                var username = user.user.username;
                var name = username.length > 10 ? username.substring(0, 12) + "..." : username;
                var { body: avatar } = await get(user.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg', size: 1024 }));
                var { body: background1 } = await get(background)
                var background2  = await fsn.readFile('assets/images/profile.png');

                return new Canvas(600, 600)
                    .setColor('#000000')
                    .addImage(background1, 0, 0, 600, 500)
                    .addBeveledImage(background2, 0, 0, 600, 400)
                    .setTextFont('30px Impact')
                    .addText(`${name}'s Profile Card`, 190, 105)
                    .setTextFont('30px Impact')
                    .addText('|', 280, 380)
                    .addText('|', 280, 400)
                    .addText('|', 280, 420)
                    .addText('|', 280, 450)
                    .addText('|', 280, 470)
                    .addText('|', 280, 495)
                    .addText('__   ___', 495, 420)
                    .addText('_______', 495, 460)
                    .addText('__   ___', 495, 520)
                    .addText('_______', 495, 560)
                    .addText('_______________________', 150, 500)
                    .setTextFont('bold 28px Courier New')
                    .addText(` About ${user.user.username}`, 180, 182)
                    .setTextFont('30px Impact')
                    .addText('Level', 190, 140)
                    .addText('Ranks', 310, 140)
                    .addText('Works', 445, 140)
                    .setTextFont('30px Impact')
                    .addText('Total XP', 180, 530)
                    .addText('Balance', 180, 560)
                    .addText(`${crFormat(xp)}`, 370, 530)
                    .addText(`$${crFormat(balance)}`, 370, 560)
                    .setTextAlign('center')
                    .setTextFont('bold 20px Courier New')
                    .setTextFont('30px Impact')
                    .addText(`${uLevel}`, 280, 140)
                    .addText(`${vip}`, 410, 140)
                    .addText(`${crFormat(work)}`, 555, 140)
                    .addText('-', 260, 140)
                    .addText('-', 393, 140)
                    .addText('-', 535, 140)
                    .setColor("#459466")
                    .addRect(150, 570, difference, 34)
                    .setTextFont("16px RobotoRegular")
                    .setColor("#000000")
                    .setTextAlign('right')
                    .addText(`${Info}`, 210, 200)
                    .setTextAlign("center")
                    .addText(`XP: ${xp} / ${nxtLvlXp}`, 330, 590)
                    .addCircularImage(avatar, 90, 93, 89, 104)
                    .toBufferAsync();
            }

            const msg = `**User profile card for ${user.user.tag}**`;
            const attachment = new MessageAttachment(await createCanvas(), 'profile.png')
            message.channel.send(`${msg}`, attachment)

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            return message.channel.send(`Oh no an error occurred :( \`${e.message}\` try again later.`);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getWrapText: function (text, length) {
    const temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i += length) {
      temp.push(text.slice(i, i + length));
    }
    return temp.map(x => x.trim());
  },
```